# how can i measure stress testing for the iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, stress-testing, asp.net-web-api

how can i measure stress testing for the iPhone app ?
i need stress testing not performance testing, for example 100 users access the database of the app which is on the server at the same time.
any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an iphone question or a web-app question?

Comment: So you actually want to perform stress tests on the server, not the app. Can you clarify that in the question?

Comment: can i test both of them at the same time ?

Comment: What you're asking for may not be practical, since you would need 100/1000 devices. Simulating 1000 user requests will be sufficient enough to stress test just the server. Then do end-to-end testing to ensure your app works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to decide if you need to test the client-side (iPhone) app, the server-side code, or both.

Testing ONLY the server-side, might make this much easier - especially if it is using HTTP to communicate with the server and exchanges data via a text-based format (XML, JSON, etc). There are many web load testing tools available which can handle this scenario.  Using our [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/load-tester.html) product, for example, you would configure the proxy settings on your iPhone to point to our software running on a local machine. Then start a recording and use the application. Load Tester will record the messages exchanged with the server. You can then replay the scenario, *en masse*, to simulate many users hitting your server simultaneously. The process, at a high level, is the same with most of the web load testing tools.

Of course, the requests to the server can't be replayed exactly as recorded - they'll need to be customized to accurately simulate multiple users. How much customization is needed will depend on the kind of data being exchanged, the complexity of the scenario and the ability of the tool to automatically configure dynamic fields (and this is one area where the abilities of the tools vary greatly).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

A basic simulation would involve running your unit tests on OS X, using many simultaneous unit test processes (with unique simulated users, and other variables).

If you need more 'stress', add machines - you'll likely end up hitting io or network limits from one machine relatively early on.

Comment: yes. you can write a short script to start all these processes (which you could also write to be multithreaded). how do you approach stress testing without any execution?